# Net Core 2.2 AWS RHEL 7.5 Deployment

Tags: asp.net-core

I m trying to deploy my 1st ASP.NET Core 2.2 API on AWS RHEL 7.5

my /etc/systemd/system/kestrel-mytest.service

```
[Unit]
Description=.NET Prototypes Application on Linux

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/ec2-user/webapi
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/ec2-user/webapi/prototypes.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=apache
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

TimeoutStopSec=90

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

now I am facing with:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-6-33 dotnet]$ sudo systemctl status kestrel-mytest.service

â kestrel-mytest.service - .NET Prototypes Application on Linux
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kestrel-mytest.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-02-19 14:06:39 UTC; 6s ago
  Process: 3902 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/ec2-user/webapi/prototypes.dll (code=exited, status=145)
 Main PID: 3902 (code=exited, status=145)

Feb 19 14:06:39 ip-172-31-6-33.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: kestrel-mytest.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=145/n/a
Feb 19 14:06:39 ip-172-31-6-33.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit kestrel-mytest.service entered failed state.
Feb 19 14:06:39 ip-172-31-6-33.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: kestrel-mytest.service failed.
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-6-33 dotnet]$
```

what I missed?..

thanks a lot in advance

Don

Answer (score 1):

this would resolved:

- working directory MUST be the same as DocumentRoot of Apache (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf) (in my case, DocumentRoot is /var/www/html/ so, it should be:
  WorkingDirectory=/var/www/html/webapi, do does the ExecStart as below:

ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/html/webapi/prototypes.dll

things to consider:

chown -R apache:your_group /var/www/html/webapi

don't forget to stop and start kestrel to take effect.

systemctl stop kestrel-xxx 
systemctl start kestrel-xxx
systemctl enable kestrel-xxx to automate start after machine rebooted

to check dotnet listener port status

sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN

Comment: You just saved me So. Much. Time. Thank you.